# EPPLus - Opening Just The First 1000 Rows Of An Excel File From C#

Tags: epplus

Some of the Excel files I'm working with are big, and I only need to see a sampling of the data in them. The first 1000 lines is plenty.

Does anyone know of a way to open just the top of a file? Currently we're doing the following:

_package = new ExcelPackage(file);

This reads the whole file into memory. I've played with OpenXML a little bit and it looks like it's possible to read just part of a file with that, but we have a lot of code already built around EPPlus, so I'm trying to do it with EPPlus.

I believe EPPLus uses OpenXML. If anyone knows how to use the two together to read partial files and could give me some guidance, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this will help? I haven't worked with it myself. https://github.com/paulyoder/LinqToExcel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Partial Load Excel EPPlus C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32743720/partial-load-excel-epplus-c-sharp)